# Nested tableview in tab bar controller

Tags: iphone

I have a tab bar with four tabs .  One tab opens a table view with a list of items each with a disclosure  accessory  that opens another (nested) tableview.  When the disclosure detail view opens I still want to see the tabs. It currently it's  over writing the whole screen.  Any insight would be great my appreciated

Comment: how are you creating your UI?  storyboard or XIB?  do you have a screenshot of your storyboard?  do you have a code-snippet of how you're attempting to set this up?

Answer (score 0):

You should nest your UITableViewController in a UiNavigationController. If you're building your app with a storyboard, you can click on the UITableView, click on the `Editor` menu and then select Embed in  - UINavigationController. And you're done.